# Why not codereview.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible codereview.stackexhcange.com to be codereview.stackoverflow.com?

reasons:

- I have seen some questions on stackoverflow.com implicitly asked to review code.
- Both websites about programming, so why not combine both in the domain stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are a sibling site of stackoverflow not a daughter site. All of these sites are under the umbrella of stackexchange. Since code review isn't part of stackoverflow, it makes no sense for us to be under their domain.

Comment: Indeed. stackoverflow technically should be stackoverflow.stackexchange! #snark

Comment: I like the family-relations metaphor. :D